# Where to add citation when having several paragraphs from the same source(s)?

Tags: citations

So, if I have three paragraphs, inspired and even having copied sections from the same source, do I add citation at the end of each paragraph or at the end of the third or where else?

Comment: is it a consecutive sequence of three paragraphs that you're quoting ? are you quoting them in the same place ?

Comment: yes, the paragraphs are one after the other and the two sources are used for all of them...

Comment: actually there is one source... the second is also inspired from the first

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/8804/2692

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have such a substantial chunk of information attributable to one source it can be useful to start the text by simply declaring the source. This can be done in the following way (exact formulation can of course be changed; I chose Harvard style referencing as an example):

> The following [x] paragraphs follow Name (yyyy) unless stated otherwise.

The formulation can be changed to better blend in with the text by adding details about what the information is about  or why this source is good or should be repeated, or both. The "unless stated otherwise" can be omitted if you have no need to add other references in these paragraphs; I added it for completeness.