# What kind of citation is needed for a whole paragraph?

Tags: citations

I'm writing a paper on The Beatles and in this paragraph I'm talking about the formation of the group. I got the info from their biographical book. So it's just a summarized version of a chapter. I have no idea how to state that this info is from a book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing a chapter in a paragraph and citing it at the end, I think, is not a good idea.

It is better to write

> Simpson mentions the formation of the group in Chapter 5 of History
>   of The Beatles [12].

And then write your paragraph in italic.

Actually, if you can, put citations at the end of each 2-3 sentences.
The following example is more proper when writing an academic manuscript.

> The Famous English Rock Band Beatles was formed in 1957 [34]. First,
>   John Lennon, the founder of the band, named the band as The Blackjacks. Then, with Paul McCartney joining the band, the name was changed
>   to The Quarrymen [21].

Answer (score 2):

You are paraphrasing the material, not quoting it.  (You summarized it.)  Put the citation at the end of the paragraph and add the source to your bibliography.